# nested HTML tables with bootstrap grid

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following plunker code: https://plnkr.co/edit/SKEFmvY3yG0eXPcC7oKu?p=preview

I am trying to create a table which looks like this (note the bottom border cutoff but it should be there!): [image: following]

The end goal will be to recreate a nested structure (or something similar) using angular directives. The current code has issues with table bordering and the tables not looking as though theyre joined correctly (it should look like the above picture).

This is the html code I have:

```
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th colspan="1">
                  Name: Logic Response
                </th>
                <tr>
                  <td class="field-label col-md-6 active">
                    <label> Action: </label>
                    <label> action.logic </label>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100%" class="col-md-12" colspan="1">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="col-md-6">
                            Key
                          </th>
                          <th class="col-md-6">
                            Value
                          </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="col-md-6">
                            repetition.count
                          </td>
                          <td class="col-md-6">
                            1
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="1">
                    Name: Logic Response
                  </th>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="field-label col-md-6 active">
                      <label> Action: </label>
                      <label> action.logic </label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-12" colspan="1">
                      <table width="100%" class="table table-bordered">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-6">
                              Key
                            </th>
                            <th class="col-md-6">
                              Value
                            </th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-6">
                              repetition.count
                            </td>
                            <td class="col-md-6">
                              1
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

          </td>
          </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with my own solution here: https://plnkr.co/edit/J2sdqgTxL4beneAOXMR1?p=preview

Basically, rather than nesting the tables I ended up adding a `style="margin-bottom:0;"` value and created multiple tables to give the apperance of a single table.

The code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="margin-bottom:0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1">
            Name: Logic Response
          </th>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label col-md-6 active">
              <label> Action: </label>
              <label> action.logic </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100%" class="col-md-12" colspan="1">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-6">
                      Ayy
                    </th>
                    <th class="col-md-6">
                      Value
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-6">
                      repetition.count
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-6">
                      1
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover margin-bottom:0;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="1">
            Name: Logic Response
          </th>
          <tr>
            <td class="field-label col-md-6 active">
              <label> Action: </label>
              <label> action.logic </label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100%" class="col-md-12" colspan="1">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-6">
                      Ayy
                    </th>
                    <th class="col-md-6">
                      Value
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-6">
                      repetition.count
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-6">
                      1
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```